# Using FORCE INDEX with zend

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I try to find how to translate the following MySQL query into Zend Db Table Select:

```
SELECT ColA,ColB,ColC
FROM MyTable
FORCE INDEX(ColA,ColB)
WHERE ColA = 'val0002'
AND ColB = 'val0045'
```

i try to use something like this:

```
$select = $dbTable->select()
            ->from('MyTable',array('ColA','ColB')
            ->forceIndex(array('ColA','ColB'))
            ->where("ColA = 'val0002'")
            ->where("ColB = 'val0045'");
```

I found " forceIndex(array('ColA','ColB')) " in a forum, but it does not work :(

and thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `Zend_Db_Select` doesn't support it yet. There seems to be an improvement request about it here: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-7570

(The report comments contain some links to code that could be useful to you).

Hope that helps,

Comment: is too bad that this method MySQL, has not equivalent in Zend, it greatly increases the performance of a query. waiting to find a solution in the next Zend version.

Answer (score 1):

here's a solution that can help interested by the problem :
http://pastie.org/1354770

we can add the following two methods to the zend class "Zend_Db". I hope it will help you as it helped me (but partially).

```
/**
 * Specify index to use
 *
 * @return Zend_Db_Select
 */
public function useIndex($index)
{
    if(empty($this->_parts[self::FORCE_INDEX])) {
        if(!is_array($index)) {
            $index = array($index);
        }
        $this->_parts[self::USE_INDEX] = $index;
        return $this;
    } else {
        throw new Zend_Db_Select_Exception("Cannot use 'USE INDEX' in the same query as 'FORCE INDEX'");
    }
}

/**
 * Force index to use
 *
 * @return Zend_Db_Select
 */
public function forceIndex($index)
{
    if(empty($this->_parts[self::USE_INDEX])) {
        if(!is_array($index)) {
            $index = array($index);
        }
        $this->_parts[self::FORCE_INDEX] = $index;
        return $this;
    } else {
        throw new Zend_Db_Select_Exception("Cannot use 'FORCE INDEX' in the same query as 'USE INDEX'");
    }
}
```