# After DB version change, index won't be used automatically

Tags: mysql, database, magento, amazon-web-services, mysql-5.6

We recently migrated our Magento application from a private host to AWS web services. We noticed that some of the internal functionality of Magento was taking an excessively long period of time to execute after the migration, so started to investigate.

One of the queries in question is a simple customer select query, with around 9-10 regular joins to attribute tables to get the attributes.

We have run some tests on the query and found that the difference between the old host and AWS is that on the old host, the MySQL optimizer appears to use the correct index, whereas in AWS it resorts to using filesort, ignoring the index.

[Using `FORCE INDEX(index_name)`](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/7-ways-to-convince-mysql-to-use-the-right-index) makes the query execute correctly in AWS, however we don't want to go down this road and would rather fix the issue in the database configuration than make [manual hacks throughout our Magento application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442637/using-force-index-with-zend/7517587#7517587). To be clear, [this is **not** an issue with our indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48072/why-does-mysql-ignore-the-index-even-on-force-for-this-order-by), they are set up correctly.

For background:

- I have copied all the MySQL parameters from the old host's my.cnf file to a parameter group in RDS, but nothing made any difference
- The tables are all InnoDB
- I've run analyze, repair and optimize queries etc
- The query takes around 45 seconds to complete on RDS
- The query took around 2 seconds to complete on the old host, or when I use `FORCE INDEX()` to force RDS to behave in the same way as the old host

The old MySQL server was running version **5.1.61**, and the AWS RDS instance we are running is on **5.6.19**. A consulting group suggested to us that we downgrade our RDS instance to 5.1.61, however again we don't want to do this as it is not a sustainable solution.

The query in question is below (shortened by removing fields from the select for the sake of space):

```
SELECT
    `e`.*
    -- various field names here, removed
FROM `customer_entity` AS `e`
LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_int` AS `at_default_billing` ON (`at_default_billing`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_default_billing`.`attribute_id` = '13')
LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_postcode` ON (`at_billing_postcode`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_postcode`.`attribute_id` = '30')
LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_city` ON (`at_billing_city`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_city`.`attribute_id` = '26')
LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_telephone` ON (`at_billing_telephone`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_telephone`.`attribute_id` = '31')
LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_regione` ON (`at_billing_regione`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_regione`.`attribute_id` = '28')
LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `at_billing_country_id` ON (`at_billing_country_id`.`entity_id` = `at_default_billing`.`value`) AND (`at_billing_country_id`.`attribute_id` = '27')
LEFT JOIN `core_store` AS `at_store_name` ON (at_store_name.`store_id`=e.store_id)
LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `firstname` ON e.entity_id = firstname.entity_id AND firstname.attribute_id = 5
LEFT JOIN `customer_entity_varchar` AS `lastname` ON e.entity_id = lastname.entity_id AND lastname.attribute_id = 7 

WHERE (`e`.`entity_type_id` = '1') 

ORDER BY `e`.`entity_id`
DESC LIMIT 20;
```

A summary of the differences between servers when `EXPLAIN`ing this query is below:

**RDS - MySQL v5.6.19:**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: e
         type: ref
possible_keys: IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID
          key: IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID
      key_len: 2
          ref: const
         rows: 653990
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
```

**Old host - MySQL v5.1.61, or when `FORCE INDEX` is used on RDS:**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: e
         type: ref
possible_keys: IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID
          key: IDX_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID
      key_len: 2
          ref: const
         rows: 644775
        Extra: Using where
```

I'm aware that it's highly likely that the difference in those database versions has changed the way the query optimizer works, and I'm not aware of what the differences in those versions are, but I'm looking for a solution that will help us to address those differences.

---

**Edit:** here's a comparison list from RDS for the parameters I've copied over from the old host vs the default parameters for this MySQL version. None of these parameters have affected the result above whether they are there or whether I used standard parameters in RDS:

[image]

Comment: Hard to answer on Stack Overflow, since it's likely going to be some small subtle part of your configuration that fixes it.  Posting the table definitions somewhere might help.

Comment: I can post the table definitions if you'd like, but as I say they're standard Magento tables

Comment: What happens (in terms of index usage) if you remove the order by in your query on RDS and do the explain plan again?

Comment: Hi Brian, removing the ORDER BY stops the query from using indexes or filesort entirely, as it doesn't need to order anything.

Comment: @scrowler I doubt it has to do something with the memory allocation to MYSQL. How much you allotted to Mysql in your old and new server?

Comment: Is there any difference in total gigs of RAM in both the servers?

Comment: Old server is around 100gb, new server is 64gb.

Comment: Ok, do you see much difference in mysql variables in old and new server? Like for innodb_buffer_pool_size, etc?

Comment: Essentially what I did was copy every value from the old server's configuration over to parameters in RDS when I noticed that the RDS values were lower or less than the previous host. My inclination would be to say that *if* this is a variable/parameter issue within MySQL configuration, it's going to be something that I haven't tried already (I'll post a list of the values I've changed and tried).

Comment: Yes please. I doubt that because if mysql could not fill all the results in the memory to order/sort the results, it uses temporary table and filesort and that takes lot of time.

Comment: sort_buffer_size seems too small, can you try increasing it and restart mysql to test? Just my thought.

Comment: Sorry 4M seems good for sort_buffer_size.. misleading variable name :)

Comment: Hi @RobbieAverill, we are experiencing almost the same issue. What did you do in the end?

Comment: Hi Javier- you're not going to like this, but we got involved with the bug report and moved on. We haven't had reports from our users that it's still happening, however I haven't run a test lately to see if it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the query you provided, it looks like you *might* be getting snagged by [Bug #74030](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74030). A patch was contributed for a later version (5.6.20 and 5.7.4), but hasn't been applied yet, looking at the [release notes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/).  It might be good to sign-in and vote for that bug.

For now, as much as it pains me, your consultant group may be right (accidentally, perhaps)..until the patch is applied.

Answer (score 1):

My bet is on MySQL conf:

- metadata stats: from 5.6 innodb_stats_on_metadata default value changed to off. It can really change the query plan.
- now that you already ran a bunch of queries on your new installation, you could still use mysqltuner script, it's always good trying.
- please note that 5.6 changed default innodb_file_per_table to 1 and Query Cache is disabled. You can find other default changes here: https://blogs.oracle.com/supportingmysql/entry/server_defaults_changes_in_mysql

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a case mentioned in the documentation regarding the optimizer not being able to figure out the proper index because the key used to select the data is different than the one used to sort the data.

I can't speak to any changes from version to version, but here is the blurb that speaks to this case:

> In some cases, MySQL cannot use indexes to resolve the ORDER BY, although it still uses indexes to find the rows that match the WHERE clause. These cases include the following:
>
> The key used to fetch the rows is not the same as the one used in the ORDER BY:
>
> `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE key2=constant ORDER BY key1;`

Here is the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/order-by-optimization.html) in question, it offers up some suggestions to correct things. I'm not sure what you have tried already though.

Comment: Thanks, but I've mentioned that it's not an index issue :-)

Comment: My answer attempts to tell you why it's not using the index, not that you have index issues. Your options might include adding another index (you already said you don't need to do this) to cover this situation or might tell you how to rewrite your query so the optimizer will use the index that's already created. See what happens when you remove the order by. Does it use the index you expect? If so, you should be able to figure out how to rewrite your query so the optimizer can use what indexes you have.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your info. I have already been through the documentation and ensured that the correct indexes are in place. I've *ensured* that they are correct by recreating every possible combination of column indexes, including up to three columns in some cases, and have found that the existing indexes still take preference in the list of indexes that show in the explain query, although none of them get used. In this particular case, I've created an index on entity_typd_id and entity_id, and vice-versa - although the tables already contain these grouped indexes.

Comment: Just thought I'd add a bit more info - rewriting this query would fix the problem of course, however the symptoms of this query are being shown throughout the entire application, so rewriting is really out of the question.. And further, this query and the others affected are essentially straight-out-of-the-box Magento queries

Comment: I didn't realize more than one query was a problem. So this is really an example of one query that is affected by the version differences then?

Comment: Correct. I'm actually much more interested in the section at the bottom of the documentation you linked to talking about DB parameters that can be changed to help prevent using filesort. I have tried changing the sort_buffer_size variable and read_rnd_buffer_size on RDS to what they were on the previous host, but no joy there either.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't see anything in the manual for tweaking the optimizer for 5.6 but there are a few other links in 5.1. Not sure if these are helpful but here you go. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/switchable-optimizations.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/controlling-query-plan-evaluation.html